# Where have I used the assumption that $X\in L_2$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expectation, characteristic-functions

Let $X\in L_2$ be a random variable and $g$ a positive real function. Let $I$ be an interval and $b>0$, and suppose that $\forall x\in I\ g(x)>b$. I have to show that:

$$\operatorname E(g(X))\geq \operatorname P(X\in I) b$$

Well,

$$\operatorname E(g(X))=\int_\Omega g(X)\ d\operatorname P\geq \int_\Omega g(X)\chi_{X^{-1}(I)}d\operatorname P$$

Where $\chi_{X^{-1}(I)}$ is the characteristic function of $X^{-1}(I)$.

$$\geq b\int_\Omega\chi_{X^{-1}(I)}d\operatorname P=b\operatorname P(X^{-1}(I))=b\operatorname P(X\in I)$$

If this is correct, then where did I use $X\in L_2$?

Comment: It is correct.  You didn't use that assumption, and it isn't needed.

Comment: no hypothesis other than $g>-c, c\in \Bbb R$ is needed. If it is not, LHS could be undefined; if you make sure that $g > -c$ then the worst thing that can happen is that the LHS is $\infty$, in which case the result is meaningless (but coherent, at least). This is the Markov inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality

Comment: @RobertIsrael Actually, I think it might be required in the next question, which is to use the above to prove Markov's and Chebyshev's inequalities. Would it be required there?